# terraform null_resource does not trigger S3 bucket update's chained action update CloudFront distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-cloudfront

Before I used the resource `aws_s3_object` for syncing local files to S3 bucket. Back then updates in S3 triggered updating the connected distribution in CloudFront.

Now I replaced only the resource `aws_s3_object` mentioned above by `null_resource` / `provisioner "local-exec"` in the project. Then `terraform apply` only detected changes for the S3 bucket and no longer triggered updates for CloudFront.

What I did wrong / was missing here?

The related code:

**Before** (CloudFront is updated when S3 is updated):

```
resource "aws_s3_object" "site" {
  for_each     = fileset("./site/", "*")
  bucket       = xyz.id
  key          = each.value
  source       = "./site/${each.value}"
  etag         = filemd5("./site/${each.value}")
  content_type = "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
}
```

**After** (only S3 is updated, CloudFront is not updated):

```
resource "null_resource" "remove_and_upload_to_s3" {
  triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws s3 sync ${path.module}/site s3://${aws_s3_bucket.xyz.id}"
  }
}
```

Comment: The claimed fact "Back then updates in S3 triggered updating the connected distribution in CloudFront." in the question may be not true. Eventually, with the hint from @Marko E below I found out cache settings actually caused the mentioned issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the issue is that the objects are kept the same even after the objects get updated, it seems that the problem with CloudFront is that the cache TTL is not set. There are [multiple ways](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html) to do this:

> By default, each file automatically expires after 24 hours, but you can change the default behavior in different ways:

> To change the cache duration for all files that match the same path pattern, you can change the CloudFront settings for Minimum TTL, Maximum TTL, and Default TTL for a cache behavior. For information about the individual settings, see Minimum TTL, Maximum TTL, and Default TTL in Values that you specify when you create or update a distribution.

> To change the cache duration for an individual file, you can configure your origin to add a `Cache-Control` header with the `max-age` or `s-maxage` directive, or an `Expires` header to the file.

Another option to do this (which can be very expensive depending on the number of objects, so be careful) is to invalidate the CloudFront cache each time you update the objects, using the `terraform_data` source:

```
resource "terraform_data" "remove_and_upload_to_s3" {
  for_each     = aws_s3_object.site
  triggers_replace = [
    each.value.etag
  ]

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id <your CF distribution id> --paths "/example-path/${each.value.key}"
  }
}
```

Note that you can also specify multiple paths if needed. Additionally, this will work only if the objects have the new objects have the same name as the old ones.

Comment: The reason why I replaced my resource aws_s3_object.site with null_resource.remove_and_upload_to_s3 in the first place is my site started having nested directories.

Comment: Ah, wait, so the S3 bucket does get updated, right? So the issue is that the CloudFront distribution is still showing the old version of the object?

Comment: Yes, it was my situation.

Comment: @Mako I've updated the answer as it seems it's more relevant to the problem you have.

Comment: I needed a long way to start understanding caching in CloudFront and browsers and your answer actually made a lot of sense. The claimed fact in my original question ("Back then updates in S3 triggered updating the connected distribution in CloudFront.") may not even be true. Now with proper cache-control headers set for objects in S3 I can even control caching behavior in CloudFront and browsers for individual resources (index.html shall be only cached shortly, hashbased-versioned css and js shall be cached for a long time). Thank you @Marko E for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: @Mako glad I could help. Acceptance of the answer would be much appreciated.